# Which constructor of tf2_ros::TransformListener should I use?

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, transform, tf2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There are two constructors of `tf2_ros::TransformListener`:

1. `TransformListener(tf2::BufferCore& buffer, const ros::NodeHandle& nh, bool spin_thread)`
2. `TransformListener(tf2::BufferCore& buffer, bool spin_thread)`

It seems that `nh` parameter in the first one is ignored, so they are equivalent. Is it accurate?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/347044/which-constructor-of-tf2_ros::transformlistener-should-i-use?/) by [pauljurczak](https://answers.ros.org/users/47807/pauljurczak/) on ROS Answers with karma: 85 on 2020-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you pass in the NodeHandle it will use that nodehandle passed. If you don't pass one it will default construct a NodeHandle to be used.

For most common use cases where the user has a default constructed NodeHandle, it will not make a difference. However by passing in the NodeHandle you have more control of things like the Callback Queue and other NodeHandle level settings that can be modified on the passed in NodeHandle.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2020-03-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2020-03-19**:
Just from glancing at it -- the nodehandle is only used to create subscribers. If the `/tf` is globally namespaced, what other nodehandle parameterizations would effect the listener? I genuinely don't see where it could be used unless the `/` in the topic was removed.

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2020-03-19**:
As I mentioned above the first thing that comes to mind is being able to control the threading via the use of custom callback queues. For example if you set it up right you can run the whole system in a single thread or at the other end enable a multi threaded callback queue.